# Power BI Dashboard Does not refresh in Big TV

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Just deployed Power BI dashboard on Big Screen 60"

Even though data refresh every half an hour, yet charts and graphs do not reflect this refresh.

They stay the same showing same information, till I reload or refresh the browser manually.

Any solution for this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you are showing a dashboard and not the report itself? Tiles in a dashboard will refresh automatically after data refresh, while reports will not. With refreshes every 30 minutes, this must be premium capacity, right? Check is query caching turned off. Also why you added `powerbi-embedded` tag? Is this dashboard embedded in your app, or you are showing it from powerbi.com directly?

Comment: Also, make sure you haven't pinned the whole report to the dashboard. Dashboard will refresh automatically for individual visuals only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is refreshing on the back end per the schedule you've set. It doesnt automatically update the report after you've viewed it. You need to automate the page refresh. So you need to use another mechanism to force the page you are showing to refresh on some schedule to see the up dated data that was updated on the backend.

Here are some techniques you could utilize on the page you are displaying the powerbi dashboard from so that it refreshes every 30 minutes

HTML approach

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1800; URL=http://www.yourdomain.com/yoursite.html">
```

JavaScript approach

```
setTimeout(function(){
   window.location.reload(1);
}, 1800000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Chiming in here for anyone who might see this. I've made a custom Power BI app called [Displagent](https://www.displagent.io) for showing Power BI digital signage and slideshows on TVs and other displays, so I've had to work a lot with the [Power BI JavaScript SDK](https://github.com/microsoft/PowerBI-JavaScript) and the Power BI embedded ecosystem.

As someone else stated, Power BI dashboards should automatically refresh themselves. If you are embedding a Power BI dashboard via the JavaScript SDK, there is no built in JavaScript method for "refreshing" a dashboard. However, for the dashboard to refresh, the reports that the dashboard's visuals were pinned from must also refresh. Not trying to state obvious facts, just want to make sure all of the bases are covered.

Now, if you're talking about a Power BI report - which I'm guessing is what you *actually* meant - then that is different. The Power BI JavaScript SDK does in fact have a `.Refresh()` method for Power BI reports. The effect of the `.Refresh()` depends upon your Power BI dataset's storage mode:

- For Import Mode, the `.Refresh()` method does not force a scheduled refresh. Instead, it checks the dataset's cache in the Power BI Service, and if it finds new data in the cache, it brings that data into your report instance and forces the visuals on the report canvas to update.
- For Direct Query, the `.Refresh()` method actually forces a DQ-type refresh, reaching out to your datasources and bringing in new data to your report instance.

So to have visuals auto-updating, you need to first understand what storage mode your Power BI dataset uses; then, you can understand how to use the `.Refresh()` method.

Someone else referenced refreshing the browser page on a recurring interval, but this is a hacky, unreliable, subpar way to get your visuals to update. There are various Chrome extensions that try to attempt this, but none of them work well. Instead, you really need to use the Power BI JavaScript SDK properly, or else consider a third party app such as [Displagent](https://www.displagent.io).